# CSS - Need help figuring out where I went wrong with my dropdown menu nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621500/css-can-someone-help-me-figure-out-where-i-went-wrong-with-my-dropdown-menu-na) two days ago and got some feedback but am still having issue getting my drop down nav working. Any feedback on how I can get my drop down nav working or if there is a cleaner, simpler way to execute this?

Here is my code as it stands now with the fixes from the previous post implemented.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m7u1evj/) as well.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="template_ss.css"/> 
    <title></title>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
<!--------------------------header--------------------------->
    <div id="headerDiv">
        <div id="titleDiv">
            <p id= "titleText"><span>Ti</span>t<span>le</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="navDiv">    
            <ul class="navUL">
                <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>  
                <li>
                    <a href="#!">Top</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#!">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Plus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Constant</a></li>  
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!">Browse</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#!">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">3</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!">Random</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#!">blank</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">none</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">all</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!">Profile</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#!">My profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Edit profile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!">How it works</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="searchDiv">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="blah..." required>
                <input type="button" value="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
<!---------------------------body--------------------------->
    <div class="bodyDiv">           
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*-------------------header----------------------*/
body{
margin:0px;
}
#headerDiv{
position: fixed;
height:12%;
width:100%;
background-image:url("header.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
text-align: center;
}
#titleDiv{
width: auto;
margin: auto 0;
}
#titleText{
color:white;
font-size:130%;
text-allign:center;
font-family:verdana,san serif;
}
span:first-child{
color:red;
}
span{
color:blue;
}
.navDiv{
display:inline-block;
z-index:10;
}
.navUL{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
margin: auto 0;
padding:0;
border-top:1 solid;
border-right:1 solid;
border-left:1 solid;
width:100%;
}
.navUL:after{
content:"";
display:table;
}
.navUL li{
padding: .2em 2em;
margin:2em,2em,2em,2em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}
.navUL li:hover{
background-color:#07427c;
}
.navUL li a{
color:#fff;
}
.navUL li p{
margin:0;
}
.dropdown{
position:absolute;
display:none;
background-color:#036;
padding:0
left:0;
}
.navUL ul li:hover > ul{
display:inline;
}
.navUL>ul>li:after{
content:"\25BC";
font-size:.5em;
display:inline;
position:relative;
}
.searchDiv{
display:inline-block;
}
/*------------------body--------------------*/
.bodyDiv{
text-align:center;
float:left;
background-color:grey;
height:80%;
width:70%;
position:relative;
top:80%;
left:50%;
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: `if there is a cleaner, simpler way` is *very* broad, I would suggest being more specific about what you want to accomplish

Comment: Your post is tagged as jquery - do you want a jquery dropdown? Pure CSS? Your first post says pure CSS - here is one http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH

Comment: This has been done so many times. Use the search bar.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do? Your post doesn't say what you are wanting to do

Comment: you can use js if you wish to toggle dive on click or on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure exactly what you're looking for, since neither of your two posts specified what your question was, but from looking at your jsfiddle, I saw two noticeable fixes that were needed. First, your html body was floating up into your nav. You need to clear those floats. Secondly, your css for displaying the dropdown was invalid. You were setting a rule on `.navUL ul li:hover > ul`. Since `.navUL` is the class of the unordered list, it has no child `ul`. The proper path would be `ul.navUL li:hover ul`.

Here is an [update of your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m7u1evj/2/)

Comment: Thanks, the path correction for the dropdown seemed to do the trick for allowing the drop down to actually drop down. The only problem left is that the dropdown is now off center. I will need to look into how I will need to correct this.

Comment: @ChristianRosa just add `left:0` to your `.dropdown` style

Comment: yeah that's the weird part `left:0` is already added under `.dropdown`